# Как корректно создать из переменных дата и время дату со временем? (проблема с часовыми поясами)

Tags: javascript

Есть несколько компонентов. Один отвечает за дату, другие за время.
Дата и время получаются как:

```
let date: Date = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("date")).valueAsDate;
let timeStart: Date = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("timeStart")).valueAsDate;
```

Затем в определённом месте дата и время соединяются в одну переменную и отправляются на сервер

```
const meetStart = new Date(date.setHours(timeStart.getHours(), timeStart.getMinutes())).toJSON();
```

Есть проблема: отправляется с учётом разницы в часовых поясах (допустим, если ввели 15:10, то время на сервер время придёт как 20:10)

Как корректно создать из переменных дата и время дату со временем?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант, можно отнимать разницу времени на клиенте:

```js
function setOffset(date = new Date()) {
  myTZO = -180; //если нужен часовой пояс мск например
  date = new Date(date);
  localDate = new Date(date.getTime() + (60000 * (date.getTimezoneOffset() - myTZO)));
  return localDate;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Есть вариант все перегонять в unix ts (например с помощью moment.js) и отправлять на сервер его, а уже там переводить в нужный пояс.

Comment: Сервер живёт своей независимой жизнью и хочет, чтобы дата-время приходили уже в нужном часовом поясе

Comment: Ну, тогда с помощью того же moment.js поменяй часовой пояс перед отправкой

Comment: ```moment(date /*дата, которая уже готова*/)
.add(/*кол-во*/, 'hours' /*тип*/)
.format('MM/DD/YYYY' /*Формат, в котором сервер принимает*/)```